# MVVMCross for New Cross-Platform Project?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, mvvmcross

We have a legacy app written in C# for the Compact Framework, in that we use Niject, Sqlite (ADO.Net), JSon, Bluetooth and have localized resources.  We would like to migrate this app to iOS, Android, Net 4.5+, Win Store 8.1 and in the future WinPhone 8.1.  We have chosen Xamarin and intend to use Xamarin Forms for iOS and Android and a Universal Project for Windows 8.1 platforms.

Assuming the use of the latest MVVMCross framework (including the current beta) I have several questions:

1. What would be the advantages of using MVVMCross over another MVVM framework like MVVMLight?
2. What type of overhead in-terms of memory and performance could be expected using MVVMCross?
3. Are the target platforms and project types (Hybrid Xamarin Forms, Wpf and Universal) mentioned above supported by MVVMCross?
4. I understand MVVMCross has a SQLite Plugin, can I use ADO.net (keeping in mind the targeted platforms), Are there any other providers, if so what is supported/recommended?
5. What issues will there be with the Xamarin Forms Ioc container and the MVVMCross Ioc container, which one should be used and how to configure?
6. Will new N+x videos be added highlighting new features and how to use them, if so in what time frame?

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.  This is not an appropriate question for SO.

Answer (score 2):

Collectively, these questions really are not that suitable for stackoverflow... I suspect you may have better luck:

- asking individual technical questions that are well-defined and that you've already researched (see http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
- trying social forums and real-world meetups to get opinions and experiences.
- investing your own time in order to prototype your project using various approaches
- paying experienced consultants for their professional assistance - http://xamarin.com/consulting-partners

---

1. To compare mobile frameworks, overheads, etc. at a technical level, you can try comparison sites like http://propertycross.com/. For **opinions** you can try Twitter, forums, etc. Apart from that, you know what your app is and you probably have a good idea what the most complicated and/or most performance-sensitive parts are - so you can prototype these parts yourself in each platform.
2. See 1.
3. Yes
4. MvvmCross has provided an out-of-the-box SQLite-net plugin. You can find have plugins others have provided using searches like http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=mvvmcross&page=1 and https://github.com/search?q=mvvmcross&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93
5. If anyone knows the answer to "What issues will there be?" for any software development, then hire them.
6. N+1 videos have always been produced when they are needed and when time has been available - the intention remains the same.